# How to create body without it being part of the world

Tags: box2d

Developing a game where balls are added from the top in timely fashion. Is there a way to create a body and put it in a queue to be added later?

This is also needed for pooling purposes. When a body is removed from the game it is put in a pool and when a similar body is needed It is taken from the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a body outside of a `b2World`, as it is clearly stated in the [Box2D documentation](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html):

> You should never use new or malloc to create a body. The world won't
>   know about the body and the body won't be properly initialized.

That means you can only create a body with the method `b2World::CreateBody()`, which automatically adds the created body to the world.

However, you could create a pool of `b2BodyDef` instead of `b2Body`, as they are completely independent from bodies:

> Box2D copies the data out of the body definition; it does not keep a
>   pointer to the body definition.

And you can link the body with the corresponding body definition by using the `userData` pointer.